# How to click on a bootstrap button as per the HTML through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to click a button on webpage using selenium script but it is giving me following error using this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-primary').click()
```

Error is as follows:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button class="btn-primary btn-text  sort-filter-clear-button" type="button"> could not be scrolled into view
```

HTML of the button element:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-action bookButton" id="bookButton" data-track="FLT.RD.Book.Bottom"><span class="btn-label">Continue Booking</span></button>
```

Comment: If you want to submit `form` you can try `driver.find_element_by_id('bookButton').submit()` instead of clicking. Also note that there are more than one button with class name `"btn-primary"`, so actually you're handling wrong element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to wait for element:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "bookButton")))
button.click()
```

It will wait at least 10 seconds, until element will be clickable.

Note: you have to add some exports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

**EDIT:** you can try also js executor like this:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_id("bookButton")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

in case your button is inside an `iframe/frame`, firstly you have to switch to this `frame` and only then you can interact with this element:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME("frame_name"))))
# do your stuff
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "bookButton")))
button.click()
driver.switch_to.default_content() # switch back to default content
```

Comment: Hi Andrej thanks for the solution but after wait I am getting another errori.e. TimeoutException: Message: any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi @Kyu.ki, check if button is inside of `iframe/frame`. Also you can try js executor. I will add now in answer the sample code.

Comment: Nope it isn't under iframe, but in main class tag, please refer this URL  "https://www.expedia.com/Flight-Information?continuationId=899ea383-1e1a-4787-9719-061c9c1036ed&rfrr=&superlativeMessages[0]=CP&udpDisplayMode=regular"

Comment: I have tried now with javascript executor and it has worked for me. Try it for you as well (in my answer I have providet the sample code for `exectute_script`). PS it seems like it is not possible to click on the button without javascript executor.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared and as you mentioned of *bootstrap button*, moving forward as you are trying to invoke `click()` on the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn-primary.btn-action.bookButton#bookButton>span.btn-label"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn-primary btn-action bookButton' and @id='bookButton']/span[@class='btn-label'][contains(.,'Continue Booking')]"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Abuse? I didn't mean to abuse you. Note that `span` is simply a "container" for text node. Clicking `button` node should be sufficient to trigger required behavior

Comment: It's not abuse... it's critical feedback and I agree with him. Your locators are typically pretty bad. There's no reason to have all those attributes and classes when you have an ID. There's no reason to click on the `SPAN` when you have a `BUTTON` as @Andersson already mentioned. This doesn't add anything of value over Andrei's answer and should have never been posted